# How do I add multiple conditions to \ifthenelse?

Tags: r

Thank you in advance for any help.  How do I add multiple conditions to \ifthenelse?

I want to be able to write:

```
\ifthenelse{varType equals 'HS' and metric equals 'KPI1'}
    {do this}
\ifthenelse{varType does not equal 'HS' and metric equals 'KPI1'}
    {do something else}
```

Specifically, I want to add MSL_POP$report == 'HS' to:

```
\ifthenelse{\Sexpr{MSL_POP$exception[MSL_POP$metric == 'KPI1']} == 99999 and \Sexpr{MSL_POP$report == 'HS'}}
    {do something}
\ifthenelse{\Sexpr{MSL_POP$exception[MSL_POP$metric == 'KPI1']} == 99999 and \Sexpr{MSL_POP$report != 'HS'}}
    {do something else}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least when using package `xifthen` you can use `\OR` and `\AND` constructions, and others. Example:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{a}{b} \AND \equal{c}{d}}
{do something when both a=b and c=d}
{do something when either unequal}
```

Answer (score 5):

Nest two `\ifthenelse` conditionals to achieve the proper logic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\def\a{T}% or {F}
\def\b{F}% or {T}
AND conditional:
\ifthenelse{\equal{\a}{T}}
 {\ifthenelse{\equal{\b}{T}}{something}{something else}}
 {something else}

OR conditional:
\ifthenelse{\equal{\a}{T}}
 {something}
 {\ifthenelse{\equal{\b}{T}}{something}{something else}}
\end{document}
```